Spring kafka listener: Offsets remain after last message using ack mode manual or manual_immediate
I am using spring concurrent kafka listener in batch mode with acknowledgement set to MANUAL_IMMEDIATE.
After processing the batch, there is one remaining message in each partition which is processed but not acknowledeged. My consumer properties have enable auto-commit set to false.
I want to commit the offsets for the batch if processing is successful
@Component
public class TopicListener{

    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{@kafkaTopic}", containerFactory= "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<String, B>> list, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        processData(list)
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }

    private boolean processData(List<ConsumerRecord<String, B>> list) {
        ...
    } 
}

If I restart the application, the pending lag of 1 is not consumed. But kafka consumer shows lag of 1 in every partition.
However, when consuming the messsages through a kafka console consumer or without spring kafka (using KafkaConsumer directly) the lag pending is 0.
Why is the last message not acknowledged while using spring-kafka?
For consumers, we generally need to commit offset + 1 to, is that correct ? Could this be an issue ? How can I achieve that using spring kafka listener?
Below question mentions similar issue but has no solution:
Spring-kafka-listener: Offsets remain after last message using manual acknowledge

The logic there is like this: commits.put(part, createOffsetAndMetadata(records.records(part).get(records.records(part).size() - 1).offset() + 1));. So, we do increment an offset for commit. Any chances that you can share a simple project, so we can reproduce that on our side?
